# Unable to write multiple partitions in a single table in Bigquery while using standard sql

Tags: java, google-bigquery

I am reading data from multiple tables and creating 7 days of partition, trying to write the data in the respective day partition to adjust the changes for that particular day.

I am using the `WRITE.TRUNCATE` method to avoid duplicates. However, when writing into the table I am only getting the data for the last day partition and all the other partitions are not populated. The old job was running in Legacy SQL and was working perfectly fine, however I am trying to migrate to Standard SQL and this issue is persisting since then. Attaching the code below:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= PARTITION_CREATE_DAYS; ++i) {
      LocalDate partDate = params.referenceDate.minusDays(PARTITION_CREATE_DAYS - i);

      String query = String.format(sql, partDate.toString(), params.referenceDate.toString(),params.TableA, params.TableB, params.TableC, params.TableD);
      jobs.add(createJob(params, bq, query, partDate));

    }

    boolean allSucceeded = waitForJobs(jobs.listIterator());

    if (allSucceeded) System.out.println("Job finished successfully!");
    else System.exit(1);
  }

private static Job createJob(Params params, BigQuery bq, String query, LocalDate partDate) {
    String partition = "$" + partDate.format(BQ_PARTITION_FORMAT);
    TableId tableId = TableId.of(params.outProj, params.outDataset, params.outTable + partition);


    Job job = bq.create(JobInfo.of(QueryJobConfiguration.newBuilder(query)
        .setDestinationTable(tableId)
        //.setAllowLargeResults(true)
        .setUseLegacySql(false)
        .setUseQueryCache(true)
        .setPriority(QueryJobConfiguration.Priority.values()[params.priority == 'i' ? 0 : 1])
        .setWriteDisposition(JobInfo.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE)
        .build()));
    System.out.println("Submitted BQ job " + job.getJobId().getJob() + " for partition " + partition);

    return job;
  }

}

PARTITION_CREATE_DAYS = 8

referenceDate = current date
```

Comment: I don't know why this doesn't work, but is there a reason to run the query in this way instead of using an INSERT statement? See https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/using-dml-with-partitioned-tables#inserting_data_into_ingestion-time_partitioned_tables

Comment: @ElliottBrossard yes, i am running this job to populate data into a new table.

Comment: If that's the case, you could use CREATE TABLE... AS SELECT..., right? If you mean that you are populating new *partitions* of an existing table, then INSERT should work just fine, or you can use MERGE if there may be existing data that you want to overwrite.

Comment: this is part of an ETL flow, that is why i am this java wrapper.... also i am recreating 7 days of partition on a daily run and updating the records in the new table into their respective partition. So it has to run this way

Comment: Can you add `System.out.println(partDate)` (I am not sure what will be shown here) and `System.out.println(query)` (I expect a string) below its declaration in the `for` loop? I would like to see if it is changing over iterations since I cannot reproduce the issue.